# Using string as buffer container

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

The library i'm using offer messages received from network as `uint8_t` array, can I use `std::string` as a container for these buffers?

```
uint8_t *buffer = ...;
size_t length = ...;

std::string msg = std::string(buffer, length);
```

This constructor cause a compile error? If I use `reinterpret_cast` to cast the buffer to `char*`, it will compile, but is it well defined and legal operation?

Answer (score 2):

You can safely cast to `char*` because the Standard says `char*` can alias any other type.

```
// this would be fine
std::string msg(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), length);
```

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, you can avoid the `reinterpret_cast` and any misgivings about aliasing if you use `std::string`'s [range constructor (number 6)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```
std::string msg(buffer, buffer + length);
```

Now the initialization depends purely on converting the `unsigned char`'s (because let's face it, that's what `uint8_t` probably is) to `char`. The conversion result is implementation defined, but shouldn't really be surprising.

---

As another aside, one should also consider if `std::string` is the right abstraction here. Do you intend to treat the buffer as a string type? For a sequence of raw bytes, without any of the string baggage, perhaps `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` or `std::vector<std::byte>` can easier to work with.

Comment: Why is it implementation-defined?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - `char` behaving like `singed char` or `unsigned char` is implementation defined, and so is [\[conv.integral\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.integral#3).

Comment: Oh yes that okay.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I suppose I did fudge it a little by collapsing the standard's decision tree into a simple "it's implementation defined" :)